# can not create href link of fetched data using php from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a category list of fetched data and want to show it as link. when someone click on the fetched list from database it must open in new  tab. My code is working as it should but i want to open a new tab when someone clicks on the link with username fetched from db

> > what  should i add  to my code create a href link with username fetched from database which will open in new tab when clicked .
> >     i want convert my fetched data into link like this https://stackoverflow.com/shubham[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJbv4.png)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))
{

}
else
{
header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
<html>
<body>

<?php 

include 'inc.config.php';
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logsignup ");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo"<a href='#'>";

echo $row['username'] ;
echo"</a>";
echo "<br />";

}
?>







</body>

</html>
output:-
ankit pande
sachin
sachin
sachine
akhilesh ya
shivam
123
hello
```

Comment: echo "<a href='#' target='_blank'>"; inorder to open in new tab and instead of # give some valid link

Comment: This is html 101 stuff

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to open the links in new tab when clicked and for that you need to add "target='_blank'" in your "" tag like below :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))
{

}
else
{
header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
<html>
<body>

<?php 

include 'inc.config.php';
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logsignup ");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    ####Notice the "target='_blank'"
    echo "<a href='#' target='_blank' >";

    echo $row['username'] ;
    echo "</a>";
    echo "<br />";

}
?>
```